# Getting server error upon publishing django application to azure

Tags: python, django, azure, django-pyodbc-azure

I am trying to publish my django app to azure with a MSSQL server. I am using django-azure-pyodbc with pyodbc to connect and while it works locally, whenever I publish with mssql I get an internal server error although the publish succeeds. If I publish with the sqllite3 server that comes prepackaged, it works. I am using a virtual environment with Python 3.4, Django 1.8.4, pyodbc 3.0.10 and django-pyodbc-azure 1.8.3.0. My settings.py file is as follows.

```
DATABASES = {
   'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'db_name',
        'USER': 'u_name',
        'PASSWORD': 'p_word',
        'HOST': 'host.database.windows.net',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

I have added the webapp's outgoing IP addresses to the server hoping that was the issue but it was not. After checking the diagnostic logs I found a more detailed explanation than the 500 error but I'm not sure I understand it.

```
 ModuleName FastCgiModule

 Data1 FASTCGI_RESPONSE_ERROR
```

> Data2 Error occurred while reading WSGI handler: Traceback (most
>   recent call last): File
>   "D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\lib\site-packages\sql_server\pyodbc\base.py",
>   line 14, in  import pyodbc as Database ImportError: DLL load
>   failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application. During handling of the
>   above exception, another exception occurred: Traceback (most recent
>   call last): File "D:\Python34\Scripts\wfastcgi.py", line 711, in main
>   env, handler = read_wsgi_handler(response.physical_path) File
>   "D:\Python34\Scripts\wfastcgi.py", line 568, in read_wsgi_handler
>   return env, get_wsgi_handler(handler_name) File
>   "D:\Python34\Scripts\wfastcgi.py", line 541, in get_wsgi_handler
>   handler = handler() File ".\ptvs_virtualenv_proxy.py", line 120, in
>   get_venv_handler handler =
>   get_wsgi_handler(os.getenv('WSGI_ALT_VIRTUALENV_HANDLER')) File
>   ".\ptvs_virtualenv_proxy.py", line 78, in get_wsgi_handler handler =
>   handler() File
>   "D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\wsgi.py", line
>   14, in get_wsgi_application django.setup() File
>   "D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\lib\site-packages\django__init__.py", line
>   18, in setup apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS) File
>   "D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py",
>   line 108, in populate app_config.import_models(all_models) File
>   "D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py",
>   line 198, in import_models self.models_module =
>   import_module(models_module_name) File
>   "D:\Python34\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
>   return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) File
>   "", line 2254, in _gcd_import File
>   "", line 2237, in _find_and_load File
>   "", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>   File "", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
>   File "", line 1129, in _exec File
>   "", line 1471, in exec_module File
>   "", line 321, in
>   _call_with_frames_removed File "D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py",
>   line 41, in  class Permission(models.Model): File
>   "D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py",
>   line 139, in **new** new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta,
>   **kwargs)) File "D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py",
>   line 324, in add_to_class value.contribute_to_class(cls, name) File
>   "D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py",
>   line 250, in contribute_to_class self.db_table =
>   truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length()) File
>   "D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\lib\site-packages\django\db__init__.py",
>   line 36, in **getattr** return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS],
>   item) File
>   "D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line
>   240, in **getitem** backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE']) File
>   "D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line
>   111, in load_backend return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
>   File "D:\Python34\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 109, in
>   import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package,
>   level) File "", line 2254, in _gcd_import
>   File "", line 2237, in _find_and_load
>   File "", line 2226, in
>   _find_and_load_unlocked File "", line 1200, in _load_unlocked File "", line
>   1129, in _exec File "", line 1471, in
>   exec_module File "", line 321, in
>   _call_with_frames_removed File "D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\lib\site-packages\sql_server\pyodbc\base.py",
>   line 16, in  raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading pyodbc
>   module: %s" % e) django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error
>   loading pyodbc module: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32
>   application. StdOut: StdErr:

Comment: I am using 32-bit versions of python as well as pyodbc -- pyodbc-3.0.10-cp34-none-win32.whl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not really know how Azure works, but I got this error when mixing 32 and 64 bit driver/python combo's. Try using a x64 bit version of python and the driver.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was my coworker who is publishing was using the 64 bit version of python in his environment. Simple enough but I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue, but I did a test with your packages and versions. And I used Visual Studio to publish the Django application to Azure Web Apps, it worked fine. Here are my steps for your reference:
1,Create an empty Web App and set up deployment from local Git repo

2,Create a Django application in Visual Studio, add Virtual Environment with python 3.4, then install python packages, here is the content in `requirements.txt`:

`Django==1.8.4
pyodbc==3.0.10
django-pyodbc-azure==1.8.3.0`

3,Modify the database settings to MSSQL on Azure, press F5 to test on local

4,Right click Django application project name, click `publish` to deploy

[image]

After finishing the deployment, it will automatically browse your application in default browser.